# How does a non-developer test a dead simple, single-use, Paypal button?

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-sandbox

I'm not a programmer, a developer, or a genius. I'm a semi-intelligent person who wants to build a single-serving Web site that provides a simple service for a fixed price.

So I just need to test a single "Submit & Pay" button that I've built using a Machform form. You fill in the form, press the button, and it directs you to Paypal to complete the payment.

Everything is working until I get to the Paypal part. But I don't want to start paying Paypal fees just to check if it's working okay.

There *seems* to have been a Sandbox option in the past on Paypal, but after creating a basic Sandbox account, it... doesn't work. Links go nowhere, and even the main site (cms.paypal.com) goes to a 404 page. The "Getting Started with Sandbox" link [goes to a broken page](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/pages/global/system_error.html). The "Sandbox User Guide" [attempts to load a PDF on a site I don't know, and don't trust](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/CA/en_US/files/developer/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide.pdf).

The "Sandbox" options on the main site -- when they don't go to the semi-broken, I-guess-abandoned "Sandbox" site -- go to developer.paypal.com, which is *way* too much gun for me. Even a Google search for "paypal sandbox" now leads exclusively to developer.paypal.com links.

I just need to confirm that my "pay" button will execute correctly in Paypal; I don't need to build a multi-platform API that configures my JavaScripts to execute a parallel-stream optimization option on a scaleable interface across mobile devices with integrated IPNs and a side of fries.

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sandbox is indeed what you need for testing, and you do need an account at developer.paypal.com in order to use it.  It's not a complicated thing, though.  You don't have to get all crazy with it if you don't want/need to.

Go to http://developer.paypal.com and login there with your PayPal account.  Once logged in click on Applications and then go to Sandbox Accounts.

Use the Create Account button to create at least 1 seller account and 1 buyer account.  For the seller account just make it a business account.  For the buyer account you can make it personal or business.

Launch your sandbox seller account and login to that.  This is your fake PayPal account that you can use just like your own.  From within that account you can create buttons just like you do from your live account, and you can place those buttons on pages to test with.

Then when you launch that page in a browser and click on the button it will send you over to sandbox.paypal.com instead of the regular paypal.com, but it will all look very similar to what a buyer would see during payment.  You can use the buyer sandbox account you created to complete the purchase exactly as you would with a real account.

After that you can login to the seller or buyer account to see how things would look for each person in the transaction.

Comment: Thanks -- that was concise, clear and most of all calming. I think the PP developer site is very good at tackling developer needs, but could use a front-end guide like yours for the easily confused and panicked.